# Is there a way to set Visual Studio 2008 build verbosity on a per-solution or per-project basis?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I typically have several solutions open at once, and changing MSBuild verbosity manually has become a real chore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it Visual Studio per project (or if it's possible) but if you use Cruise Control (or about any build tool) you can modify the config file on the fly and use the build logs from CC.  This is what I did for this exact same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own build tool (Yes I know you for sure had already thought of it and were looking for an out-of-the box solution!! :-) ). We did this for processing build output and display it in a non-interleaved way...

The numbers at the start of the lines identify the project (excuse me if this was already clear for you but might help somebody else). So it is easy to parse and redistribute, to tune verbosity you can then set parameters or even modify the parts of the projects (XML) involved in it.

This will reward because you then will be able to add also some checks like are all the settings compatible with each other regarding for example wchar_t as native type or exception handling form (useful if you work on a big team and some guys tweak the stuff in the wrong way)

You can then also use this to build under a Continuous Integration Server the resulting logs will be easier to read...